# undefined is not a function (near '...(0 _reactnavigation.stacknavigator)...')

Tags: react-native

I have tried everything with google help plz someone plz get me a solution for this.

I have tried StackOverflow every answer but didn't get this

This is my route.js

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Contacts from '../screens/Contacts';
import Details from '../screens/Details';

export const ContactsStack = StackNavigator({
Contacts: {
    screen: Contacts,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Contacts',
    },
},
Details: {
    screen: Details,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Details',
    },
},
});
```

and this is index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ContactsStacks } from './config/router';

const App = () => {
   return <ContactsStacks />;
};

export default App;
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.2.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.12.1"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `createStackNavigator` instead of `StackNavigator`.

This is the change in react-navigation 3.0

**[react-navigation stack navigator.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html)**

Comment: Thanks for your help means a lot to me. After replace "createStackNavigator", getting this error now
Element type is invalid expecting a string or a class/function. You likely forgot to export your component

Comment: That's something related to import function. You might have imported the class name in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a `StackNavigator` like that.

Try this code instead:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Contacts from '../screens/Contacts';
import Details from '../screens/Details';

export const ContactsStack = createStackNavigator({
Contacts: {
    screen: Contacts,
    navigationOptions:  ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: `Contacts`,
    }),
},
Details: {
    screen: Details,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: `Details`,
    }),
},
});
```

Did you really Google?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried this as well. Don't know what  I am missing. I am new just following the tutorials.
Now he is asking that element type is invalid expecting a string or a class/function